# Postgresql, change column data TYPE from timestamp to DATE?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to migrate a column in a table from timestamp (double precision) to a Date.

For example, right now seen_timestamp column contains values like this one:

`1643302746243`

Values now are all `UTC`. So that unix timestamp would be:

`Thu, 10 Mar 54044 17:04:03 GMT`

Which is part of the mistake I made. The timestamp is supposed to be this:

`1643302746.243`

Which would be this date:

`01/27/2022, 04:59:06 PM`

So, I could first update all values by dividing by 1000, and then migrating over to UTC Date type....

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE car
ALTER COLUMN seen_timestamp TYPE DATE USING seen_timestamp::DATE;
```

I get the following error:

`cannot cast type double precision to date`

Makes sense. I just don't know how to change/migrate the column to `Date` type.

How can I make this work?

Comment: `double precision` is not a "timestamp" to begin with. A `timestamp` is a timestamp. But to answer your question we would need to know what values does the column contain?

Comment: yes, you're right. I'll update the question.

Comment: Are you sure you want a timestamp from the year 54044?

Comment: hahaha. I edited the question. Sorry.

Comment: According to https://www.epochconverter.com/ the value `1643302746243` corresponds to UTC  January 27, 2022 4:59:06.243 PM.

Comment: 1) Create a new empty column of type `TIMESTAMP` with a different name. 2) Update the new column converting the number to a timestamp. 3) Drop the existing BAD column. 4) Rename the new column to have the name of the old column.

Comment: @TheImpaler, that is because it assumes the value is in milliseconds and does the `1643302746243/1000`. From Postgres: `select to_timestamp(1643302746243); 54044-03-10 09:04:03.000064-08` and `select to_timestamp(1643302746243/1000);  2022-01-27 08:59:06-08`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the appropriate `USING` clause:

```
ALTER TABLE car
ALTER COLUMN seen_timestamp TYPE timestamp
USING to_timestamp(seen_timestamp / 1000.0::numeric);
```

Comment: Ah, silly me, I declared the column as `date` rather than as `timestamp`. Fixed. You were right all along.

Answer (score 1):

So I got it working. Both comments from `The Impaler` and answer from `Laurenz` helped get in the right direction. This is what works for me:

```
-- add new tmp column to store timestamps
ALTER TABLE car ADD COLUMN tmp_seen_timestamp timestamptz;
-- update new column using seen_timestamp values/1000
UPDATE car SET tmp_seen_timestamp=to_timestamp(seen_timestamp / 1000.0::numeric) where seen_timestamp is not null;
-- remove original column
ALTER TABLE car drop column seen_timestamp;
-- raname column...
ALTER TABLE car rename column tmp_seen_timestamp to seen_timestamp;
```

This works too, following what Laurenz posted:

```
ALTER TABLE car
ALTER COLUMN seen_timestamp TYPE timestamptz
USING to_timestamp(seen_timestamp / 1000.0::numeric);
```

This does what it needs, but, I am confused why using 'date' as type would not provide full precision.

Comment: Check out the docs for [Date/Time data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). The `date`, `timestamp`, and `timestamptz` types consume 4, 8, and 12 bytes, respectively. One reason to use `date` would be to save space. Or maybe the application would never need resolution down to hours/minutes/seconds... and it would be *extra* work every time to cast a high resolution type (date+time) to a lower resolution type (date only). It's also worth noting that there are time only data types, too. Some DB designers might wish to have date and time in separate columns.

Comment: Good info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How to update timestamp datatype in postgresql

ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME]
ALTER COLUMN [COLUMN_NAME] TYPE TIMESTAMP without time zone